# tweet favorite count

Tags: twitter

Is there any api endpoint to retrieve the shares, favorites and retweets count about a link shared on twitter?

To get the comments, likes and shares count on fb I use the following endpoint:
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=my_url

Is there any similar endpoint on twitter?

Right now I'm getting only the shared count with:
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=my_url

EDIT: this endpoint does not return the actual shared count, it's always 1.

Answer (score 1):

Retweets: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

Shares: Aren´t "Retweets" actually shares?

Favorites: I am not sure if it´s possible, there is no endpoint afaik

You can also use a platform like [sharedcount](http://www.sharedcount.com/) though, a lot easier to handle and you get all the counts in one call - for all relevant platforms. That would be the best solution if you only want to get counts.

Take a look at the "Sources" section of their old docs to see how sharedcount gets the counts: http://www.sharedcount.com/documentation.php

Twitter: `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.jsonurl=%%URL%%&callback=twttr.receiveCount`

Comment: But I actually do not have a status id, since it's just a shared url like this for example. Every user clicking on the twitter button shares the url and generate its own tweet. How can I track statistics about the shared link count? for example http://www.agrodolce.it/ricette/biscotti-digestive

Comment: check out the last part of my answer, i have added some more information.

Comment: luschn thanks but I won't use an external service, I need to use the native twitter apis.

Comment: that is why i included more information in my answer for you

Comment: I thank you luschn, I can see both the endpoints I'm using right now.

Comment: but I guess I'm asking something wrong: since by clicking the use create a new tweet it is impossible to get the favourite count "for a lot of different tweets"

Comment: i have no clue what you mean, but did you urlencode the url in the api call?

Comment: btw, works fine for me if i put in my blog: http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=www.devils-heaven.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65477/discussion-between-damiano-barbati-and-luschn).